# Tortoise ORM filter with logical operators

Tags: python, python-3.x, orm, tortoise-orm

I have two tables

```py
class User(models.Model):
    id = fields.BigIntField(pk=True)
    name = CharField(max_length=100)
    tags: fields.ManyToManyRelation["Tag"] = fields.ManyToManyField(
        "models.Tag", related_name="users", through="user_tags"
    )

class Tag(models.Model):
    id = fields.BigIntField(pk=True)
    name = fields.CharField(max_length=100)
    value = fields.CharField(max_length=100)
    users: fields.ManyToManyRelation[User]
```

Let's assume this dummy data

```py
#users
bob = await User.create(name="bob")
alice = await User.create(name="alice")

#tags
foo = await Tag.create(name="t1", value="foo")
bar = await Tag.create(name="t2", value="bar")

#m2m
await bob.tags.add(foo)
await alice.tags.add(foo, bar)
```

Now I want to count users who have both tags `foo` and `bar`, which is `alice` in this case, so it should be `1`.

The below query will give me a single level of filtering, but how do I specify that the `user` should have both `foo` and `bar` in their `tags` ?

```py
u = await User.filter(tags__name="t1", tags__value="foo").count()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tortoise-ORM provides [Q objects](https://tortoise-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/query.html?highlight=join_type#q-objects) for complicated queries with logical operators like `|`(or) and `&`(and).

Your query could be made like this:

```
u = await User.filter(Q(tags__name="t1") & 
                     (Q(tags__value="foo") | Q(tags__value="bar"))).count()
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you cannot `group_by` on the annotated field in Tortoise ORM as of now.
Here's the solution using the `having` clause referred from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52290036/mysql-many-to-many-relationship-with-multiple-and-condition)

```py
u = await User.filter(Q(tags__value="foo") | Q(tags__value="bar"))
              .annotate(count=Count("id"))
              .filter(count==2)
```

The idea is to get the records having a count equal to the number of tags, which is `2` in this case (`bar`, `foo`)